# CSS margin does not work. Why?

Tags: html, css, margin

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#a
{
    background:#33F;
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
}

#b
{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:#F00;
}

#c
{
    margin-top:50px;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:#FF0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why div#c get margin-ed from the top of the browser instead of getting distanced from the div#b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSS has a concept called margin collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> ...
>
> - both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>
>   - top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child

Answer (score 0):

you can add `position: relative;` to the #b element and `position: absolute;` to the #c element

Answer (score 0):

You are percieving this incorrectly.  It is doing exactly what you want it to -when the divs have contents.

I've inserted non breaking spaces to achieve what you were looking for.

http://jsbin.com/ifofix/2/

Below is the other fellows suggestion

http://jsbin.com/ifofix/3/